# How are strutural deficits measured by the EU comission and by the IMF?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

I was watching a show on economics, and the guests stated that the way structural deficits measured by the IMF and European Comission usually give antagonic values, and worse, the corrections made to previous estimations may in fact indicate that previous advised policy was in fact wrong and in the opposite sense.

Well, I'm looking for some references that show how both institutions measure structural deficits, and why are they problematic.

Any help would be appreciated.